# LAZ LiDAR displayed as long line in 3D

Tags: lidar

I downloaded some LiDAR data in .laz format.
The problem is that when I try to display it (for example in CloudCompare) it is just a long line.
I know that .laz is a compressed version, reading similar topic ([Laz LiDAR files displaying extremely long thin line of points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81346/laz-lidar-files-displaying-extremely-long-thin-line-of-points)) I uncompressed it into .las with Laszip but the problem still remains.
Nevertheless, another viewer, FugroViewer can visualize it correctly as you can see from the images.
Do you know why?

[image: FugroViewer]

[image: CloudCompare]

Also, how can I turn the LiDAR data into a GeoTIFF file?

Comment: What is the coordinate system?

Comment: The coordinate system is Geodetic (North American Vertical Datum 1988). The Geographic CS is NAD83.

Answer (score 0):

Looks for me like NOAA costal data. They most likely come in
North American Vertical Datum of 1988 (NAVD88) (GEOID18) meters, also known as NSRS 2010, with EPSG 6318